# How to push and delete object with 3 three properties using a single Toggle Button

Tags: reactjs

I am going to Push some objects in an array and delete them according to there specific ID.
Now the challenge is that i wants to do the both push and delete using a single toggle button.

```
this.state = {
    array: [{
        id: 1,
        name: "Abc",
        checkBoxState: true
    }, ]
}

handleData(label, value, id) {
    let obj = JSON.stringify({
        id: id,
        name: label,
        checkBoxState: value
    });
    let array = this.state.array;

    array.push(obj);
    console.log(array);
}
```

Please tell me the method how to make it possible on a single button.

For Example if i press ok button i will fetch the properties and push into an array and if i press again this button it will have to delete the object from array according to the ID.

Comment: check if the array already has this id, and remove it. Also, do not [mutate state](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#do-not-modify-state-directly)

Comment: You should be using `this.setState()` rather than updating the state through a side effect of `array.push()`

Answer (score 0):

Edit based on your comments. First check to see if the item exists in the array. If it does, delete it. If it does not add a new item. I don't have time to test but something like this may work.

```
this.state = {
 array: [{
    id: 1,
    name: "Abc",
    checkBoxState: true
 }]
}

handleData(label, value, id) {
 let array = this.state.array;
 let arrayIds = Object.values
 for (let item of array) {
  if (item.id === id) {
    let deletedObj = array.filter(item => item.id === id)
   this.setState({
     array: deletedObj,
   })
  return
 } 
}

 let obj = JSON.stringify({
  id: id,
  name: label,
  checkBoxState: value
  });
  array.push(obj);
  this.setState({
   array
  })
 }
} 
console.log(this.state.array);
}
```

Comment: Dear i merge your code with my code but it have some error. Actually i have an list on my child component if i click on an object that have to go to the array and if i click it again it have to be delete from it. If i click on another list item then  the new object have to be  added on that list

Comment: In that case I would check if the item exists in the array. If the item does not exist, delete it. If the item does not, add it

Comment: I did not understand dear